# Best (easiest?) way to display an Excel sheet in Python

Tags: python, django, excel

I've looked around on the web and haven't found a decisive answer to the question.  I see that HTML.py is available, as well as win32com.client.
I'm sure they have their pros/cons, so I guess my question is aptly said:
Whats the accepted, common, no frills way to take an XL spreadsheet and output it as a webpage?

I'm using Django btw, if that makes any difference.

EDIT:  I should have been more explicit originally.  I've manipulated my xl file to my hearts content using xlrd to read the file, and then re-writing it with xlwt.  So now I have a .xlsx file.
What I'm looking to do is output this whole  and caboodle(xlsx file) in HTML.  The grid, color formatting, the actual table itself.  NOT just the contents.
Apologies for the lack of clarity.

Comment: If you rewrote your file using xlwt, then how do you have a .xlsx file? (Not that this is of much importance.)

Comment: Used xlwt to manipulte formatting, cell contents, etc...then save using:   wb.save(join(temp_file_path, 'output.xls'))

Comment: Ah. Do you realize that `.xls` and `.xlsx` are different?

Comment: I do know there is a minor compatibility issue, right?  I think xls is for older versions of Excel and xlsx is newer versions.  But will that make any difference for outputting the file to HTML?

Answer (score 0):

[xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) is a simple library to extract data from Excel files.

Answer (score 0):

A good start to learn xlrd through some examples is this [site](http://www.youlikeprogramming.com/2012/03/examples-reading-excel-xls-documents-using-pythons-xlrd/)

Comment: I appreciate you chiming in...but did you read the question??